# How to make the JTextField smaller, not to fill up the whole space?

Tags: java, swing

Here I have a simple `buildPanel` method for the input area.
I try to use `GridLayout(7,1)`, but the first 4 `JTextField` seem to fill up the entire space of its block, and that looks quite ugly.

Is there any way to change them back to its normal size?

```
private void buildInputPenal() 
{
    dateField = new JTextField(10); //dateField should be changed to something else later
    fNameField = new JTextField(15);
    lNameField = new JTextField(15);
    pledgeField = new JTextField(10);

    charityRB1 = new JRadioButton(Charity[0]);
    charityRB2 = new JRadioButton(Charity[1]);
    charityRB3 = new JRadioButton(Charity[2]);

    radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    radioButtonGroup.add(charityRB1);
    radioButtonGroup.add(charityRB2);
    radioButtonGroup.add(charityRB3);

    charityRB1.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    charityRB2.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
    charityRB3.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

    inputPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(7,1));

    inputPanel.add(dateField);
    inputPanel.add(fNameField);
    inputPanel.add(lNameField);
    inputPanel.add(pledgeField);
    inputPanel.add(charityRB1);
    inputPanel.add(charityRB2);
    inputPanel.add(charityRB3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `GridLayout`.  `GridLayout` creates an even set of cells for each component (that is they get the same amount of space).

Instead, consider using something `GridBagLayout` instead

See [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) and [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Comment: I just did some research on the GridBagLayout. It looks highly flexible and something fits my need. I'll continue the reading, and hopefully get more feedback when I finish the editing. :)